# Wrapping a plane onto a sphere as it changes height

Tags: modeling, animation, physics, animation-nodes

Hope someone out there can help answer my question or at least direct me to a path. I want to animate a plane wrapping onto a sphere as the sphere goes through the plane.

Another way of putting it: As the sphere approaches the plane, the plane that touches the sphere begins to wrap around it taking it's shape while the rest remains flat.

basically, something like this

[image]

Thank you so much for anyone that took the time to look and help!

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52834/creating-a-liquid-bubble-effect/52894#52894 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/100615/how-to-cover-a-surface-with-cells-biological-tissue/100623#100623 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21013/morph-a-ball-into-another-terminator-t1000-style/21017#21017

Comment: thank you so much! the last link you sent out was perfect!

Comment: maybe you should give a more precise description, with some colored pictures, because the way you'll have to do it will depend on that. The Warp modifier might also be useful

Comment: Hi, here's a link of what I am trying to accomplish: https://ideas.ted.com/watch-a-cellular-biologist-animates-the-life-cycle-of-hiv-in-this-hypnotic-video/. Yeah, I understand that I probably wasn't very clear on my description. But, hopefully the video helps?